# Forgot password action, can I handle post with the same action name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the rails way, to create seperate actions for get or post?

Is it possible to have the same name but decorate the action to only run if its a get or post?

e.g.

```
'get only'
def forgot_password
end

'post only'
def forgot_passord
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails way is to have a resource -- Each method should have a responsibility.

```
resources :password_resets
```

And then you'll let a user reset their password by visiting the form:

```
link_to 'Lost your Password?', new_password_reset_path
```

And then the form will post to create a new password_reset... That will send an email with a link to show the password_reset.

```
form_tag(password_resets_path, :method=>:post) do
```

When the use enters their updated password, it will update the password_reset.

Answer (score 1):

```
# in routes.rb
resources :password_resets

# in app/controllers/password_resets.rb
class PasswordResets < ApplicationController

   def new
     @user = current_user
     # render new reset form
   end

   def create
     @user = current_user
     @new_password = User.generate_random_password
     if @user.update_attributes(:password => @new_password)
       UserMailer.password_reset(@new_password).deliver
       flash[:notice] = 'Successfully reset your password, check your email!'
     else
       flash[:error] = 'Could not reset password'
     end
     redirect_to login_path
   end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Name them differently and create two routes in `config/routes.rb`. If you really really want one action doing different things, which is not a great idea, check `request.method` or `request.get?`, `request.post?`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can rename the actions in your controller

```
#get only
def get_forgot_password
end

#post only
def post_forgot_passord
end
```

and then on your routes.rb

```
match '/forgot_password' => 'pass_reset#get_forgot_password', :via => 'get'
match '/forgot_password' => 'pass_reset#post_forgot_password', :via => 'post'
```

the :via option do the trick.